# Changes to process module in one file don't show up in another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The `process` module in `NodeJS` doesn't seem to be global. In other words, the changes I make to it in one module don't show up in other modules.

I wrote a small piece of code to confirm demo my findings. Here is the code:

*server.js*

```
import app from "./app.js";
 
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log("UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: shutting down ...");
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});
 
// Server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

*app.js*

```
import express from 'express'
 
const app = express();
 
console.log(y)    
 
export default app;
```

When I run the code with `node server.js`, I get a following error:

```
file:///tmp/node-test/app.js:5
console.log(y);
            ^
 
ReferenceError: y is not defined
    at file:///tmp/node-test/app.js:5:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
```

However when I move a line `console.log(y)` into `server.js` I get an error that looks like this:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: shutting down ...
ReferenceError y is not defined
```

Which is what I expected to see when `console.log(y)` was in `app.js`.

It looks like changes I made in `server.js` with respect to process don't show up in `app.js`. I tried to find an answer online, but came up empty. My search foo wasn't good enough.

Does anyone know what's going on and how do I fix it? Because of coding standards I cannot use `require`, I must use `import`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your program with this command:

```
node server.js
```

Then what happens is that `server.js` got compiled (so if it had a syntax error even at the end of the program by adding something obviously impossible to parse, like closing parens without opening ones like `))))` then it would end at this point with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'` or something like this. But syntax is fine. Who knows, a global variable `y` could be defined at the time it is actually executed.

Then, there is an import:

```js
import app from "./app.js";
```

So now the `app.js` gets compiled. It is syntactically ok so it is executed. Only **after** it is executed then the rest of `server.js` could continue being executed. But `app.js` references a reference to `y` that is not defined, so the exception is thrown and the entire process exits.

This is the end of executing anything. So nothing below the import in file `server.js` gets executed (you can confirm it by adding console logs below the import), **including the `process.on()` command**.

**Note:**

For using ES modules (with `import`) the order of execution is:

1. you run `node foo`
2. `foo.js` has `import {} from './bar' (can be verified statically at compile time)
3. before even the first like of `foo` gets executed, the `bar` module is compiled and executed
4. only then the `foo` module gets executed

For using CommonJS (with `require`) the order of execution is:

1. you run `node foo`
2. `foo.js` gets compiled
3. if the compilation was ok `foo` starts getting executed
4. there is `require('./bar')`
5. so now `bar` starts getting executed
6. when `bar` finishes then `foo` continues getting executed (commands after `require`)

You can verify it on simple examples:

ES Modules:

`foo.js`:

```js
console.log('foo 1');
import {} from './bar.js';
console.log('foo 2');
```

`bar.js`:

```js
console.log('bar 1');
export const x = {};
console.log('bar 2');
```

CommonJS:

`foo.js`:

```js
console.log('foo 1');
require('./bar.js');
console.log('foo 2');
```

`bar.js`:

```js
console.log('bar 1');
module.exports = {};
console.log('bar 2');
```

Running `node foo.js` for ES Modules prints:

```
bar 1
bar 2
foo 1
foo 2
```

Running `node foo.js` for CommonJS prints:

```
foo 1
bar 1
bar 2
foo 2
```

You can play with it and add different kinds of compile time and run time errors and whaat is printed last.